# What is dark parity?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, neutrinos, dark-energy, parity

What is the physical significance of the odd dark parity and even dark parity? Does it mean if a particle has odd dark parity then it is not a dark matter candidate?

Comment: Please cite the source where you encountered this term.

Comment: arXiv:1912.11950v1 [hep-ph] 27 Dec 2019

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it is the parity assigned to [WIMPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles), hypothesized particles giving rise to dark matter. Some models give a special parity, which by definition of parity is +1 or -1 to these hypothetical particles to study their interactions. How the concept is used to derive extensions of the standard model that have the WIMPS, can be found for [example here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02200)

Answer (score -1):

**Does it mean if a particle has odd dark parity then it is not a dark matter candidate?**

Why should the parity of a particle determine if it can exist or not? Particles exist (and are even a condition for parity of particles to exist) and can two parities (still hypothetical in the case of dark matter, but there are also theories explaining dm without dark matter; personally I still think it's a fiction).